# CNAME for ELB (with VPC instance) is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cname

I have created CNAME using Route 53 for a ELB (2 VPC instances added with it). Verified CNAME with http://mxtoolbox.com. It looks fine. Also `nslookup -q= CNAME.MYDOMAIN` shows my CNAME and address fine.

My problem is, CNAME.MYDOMAIN is not loading in web browser. Where as the same setup works for ELB (with EC2-Classic instances) and loading in web browser.

Is there any different CNAME setup for ELB with VPC instance and ELB with EC2-Classic instance?

Answer (score 0):

There is a diffrence,

> In Amazon EC2, Elastic Load Balancing provides a special Amazon EC2 source security group that you can use to ensure that a back-end Amazon EC2 instance receives traffic only from the ELB load balancers.

Regarding your other question,
You cannot (as far as I know) direct ELB to VPC.
ELB can only be directed to Public subnet ELB and from there to Private subnet ELB.

I suggest you read more here:
[Elastic Load Balancing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/UserScenariosForVPC.html)